# how to add background music to two scenes using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to add background music to two scenes, but I want to music to be smooth, without stoping or something like that, for now I use :

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"back_ground_music"
                                         ofType:@"wav"]];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [player play];
```

It works fine, but it stops, when move to the next scene. I dont know much about programming, so **is it possible? If yes, then how can I do that?**

Comment: By moving that code into a class which in independent of the scenes (view controllers). This would be a model class, read about model-view-controller design pattern.

Comment: yeah, it work, but I have 4 scenes that use same viewController, but I want music only on two, is that possible?

Comment: Add an api to the model such as something StartPlaying() StopPlaying() and call them as appropriate from the relevant view controllers.

Comment: @SausageMachine thank you for your help!